# Type cast using getClass method

Tags: java, automation, cucumber

I have a method to set permission for a particular API call as shown below:

```
public void addPermission(){
GetConfig request = (GetConfig) scenarioContext.get().get("request");
request.addPermission("Admin|Manage");
}
```

Now, when I run another API, let's say UpdateConfig, I create a class for it and in addPermission, I write the above same code again but only the typecasting will change.

```
public void addPermission(){
UpdateConfig request = (UpdateConfig) scenarioContext.get().get("request");
request.addPermission("Admin|Manage");
}
```

Is there any way I can write this method in such a way that it will do something like below:

```
public void addPermission(){
Class toCast = scenarioContext.get().get("request").getClass();
toCast request = (toCast) scenarioContext.get().get("request");
}
```

Of course, this code snippet doesn't work but I think it was a good way to explain what I'm trying to achieve.
I tried to go through generics as well but couldn't quite find a way to do this.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: You should consider using an interface for that.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```java
public void addPermission()
{
  Class<?> toCast = scenarioContext.get().get( "request" ).getClass();
  var request = toCast.cast( scenarioContext.get().get( "request" ) );
  request.addPermission( "Admin|Manage" );
}
```

I am not sure what the compiler thinks about the type of `request` afterwards, so I cannot tell whether the `request.addPermission( "Admin|Manage" );` line compiles as it is written here. If I should guess, I would say that the compiler would see `request` as of type `Object` and that would prevent the following line from being compiled.

But to be honest, I have serious doubts about your design: to which class(es) will this method `addPermission()` belong (the outer one)? And what do you want to achieve with that 'generalisation' that you are asking for?

The comment from Johannes Kuhn to consider an interface for that stuff makes a lot of sense to me.